# Views Filters Populate + Autocomplete

Tags: views, ajax

I want to search in one text field on **2 values**. I'm using the [Views Filters Populare module](https://drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate) for this. This works perfectly. But how can I have an **autocomplete** on this one text field and show both the fields that are searched for?

This is what I have now in my View:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the same views you can use filters in global variables and this module https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters you can make this